# Ошибка при получении токена oauth2

Tags: php, oauth2

Пытаюсь привинтить oauth2. 
Меня интересует тип аутентификации именно user-credentials:
https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/user-credentials/
Тоесть по логину и паролю.

**Копипаст с доков:**

```
$users = array('bshaffer' => array('password' => 'brent123', 'first_name' => 'Brent', 'last_name' => 'Shaffer'));
$storage = new \OAuth2\Storage\Memory(array('user_credentials' => $users));
$grantType = new \OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($storage);

$server = new \OAuth2\Server($storage);
$server->addGrantType($grantType);
$server->handleTokenRequest(\OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Ответ от сервера:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials were not found in the headers or body"}
```

К примеру в типа Client Credentials все работает. Но нужен именно через логин и пароль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго разбирался с данной проблемой у себя 
вот в этой строчке

```
$storage = new \OAuth2\Storage\Memory(array('user_credentials' => $users));
```

используется класс Memory который, как оказалось работает с типом базы данных, который отличался от моего. Я использовал MySQL а для него вместо Memory нужно использовать PDO

```
$storage = new \OAuth2\Storage\PDO(...);
```

Классы Memory и PDO  отличаются друг от друга, даже во входных данных, я думаю вам нужно начать с изучения класса, который сопоставим с типом вашей базы данных.

$server->handleTokenRequest(\OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();

вот эта строка должна вызывается при выполнении запроса GET, т.е вы должны сделать запрос на получение токена куда должны входить входные параметры: client_id, client_secret, username, userpass. Уберите его в отдельный файл как сказано в документации (token.php)

В вашем случае верхние строки как бы отрабатывается, но $server->handleTokenRequest ждет параметры и так как он не находит client_id в запросе он выдает ошибку

Comment: Да спасибо. Все дело было именно в client_id и client_secret.

Comment: В спецификации это не обязательно, но разработчики библиотеки очень настаивают.

Answer (score 0):

Эта библиотека обязует передавать еще client_id и client_secret

https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/issues/53